# tr replace not with space but delete char

Tags: tr

I have a string `animal: dog` and I would like to `tr`ansform to have just `animal dog` (one space between).

e.g:

```
echo 'animal: dog' | tr ':' ' '
animal  dog
```

There's 2 spaces above.

I tried making the replace an empty string but:

```
echo 'animal: dog' | tr ':' ''
tr: when not truncating set1, string2 must be non-empty
```

I can get desired outcome with -s but then I have to call tr twice. Is there a way to do it in a oner?

```
echo 'animal: dog' | tr ':' ' ' | tr -s ' '
animal dog
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `-d` option. `echo animal: dog | tr -d :` outputs `animal dog`.